# Passing multiple values in a Parameter in Informatica

Tags: informatica

How to pass multiple values to a parameter and use that parameter in IN clause in Informatica for validation.
For ex:
$$DEPT_ID=20,30,40 -- Defining a parameter with multiple parameter values in param file
IN(DEPT_ID,$$DEPT_ID) -- use the same parameter in Router/Filter transformation using IN clause

Just to re-iterate this requirement is to use the parameter using IN clause in transformations, not in the SQ override.

Any pointer will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should be able to do that using mapping parameter. Try selecting the IsExprVar when defining the parameter in "Parameter and Variables" window.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the parameter as $$DEPT_ID=',20,30,40,50,'... so on, put additional ',' in front and back of the string as I did above.

Now let's say you want to check condition like IF EMP_DEPT_ID IN($$DEPT_ID) in router/Filter transformation then write code as below:

Step 1.In Expression::create and set a variable v_EMP_DEPT_ID=','||EMP_DEPT_ID||','

Step 2.In Router/Filter transformation :: INSTR($$DEPT_ID,v_EMP_DEPT_ID) >0